# How to convert in asp.net mvc string into int with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I convert string to integer using LINQ?

See below for what I have tried so far.

```
public ActionResult ViewStudent()
{
var std = from s in db.Students
          select new StudentViewModel()
          {
             student_id = s.student_id,
             student_name = s.student_name,
             student_age =s.student_age,
             student_address = s.student_address
           };

    var age = std.Average(s => Convert.ToInt32(s.student_age));//error 
    var nostd = std.Count();
    ViewBag.totalstd = nostd;
    ViewBag.stdage = age;

    return View(std);
}
```

Comment: What issue are you encountering? You fail to describe a problem.

Comment: How to convert string into int. while running problem seen like this Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 ToInt32(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to supply additional information that should have been there from the beginning.

Comment: Would it not be better to change the datatype of `age` to an `int` in the database?

Answer (score 3):

Linq to Entities does not know how to convert `Convert.ToInt32` into `SQL`.

You can either update the database so the age column is an `int` rather than a `string`.

Or you can use `ToList()` so you are then using Linq to Objects.

So something like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewStudent()
{
   var std = (from s in db.Students
      select new StudentViewModel()
      {
         student_id = s.student_id,
         student_name = s.student_name,
         student_age =s.student_age,
         student_address = s.student_address
       }).ToList();

  var age = std.Average(s => Convert.ToInt32(student_age));
  var nostd = std.Count();
  ViewBag.totalstd = nostd;
  ViewBag.stdage = age;

  return View(std);
}
```

Please note though that this will select everything from `db.Students`table in the database and load it into memory

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

A method to try to parse to int32:

```
public static int ParseInt32(string str, int defaultValue = 0)
{
    int result;
    return Int32.TryParse(str, out result) ? result : defaultValue;
}
```

And in your linq statement, do this:

```
var age = std.Average(s => ParseInt32(s.student_age));
```

Comment: student_age is in string.

Comment: ok, then use my suggested solution. this will work for you. the ParseInt32 will try to parse the passed string (student_age) to int, if successful, then you get the int back and if not then you get 0 back. so you will avoid exceptions and errors

Comment: Oh alaa_Sayegn I am new in asp.net mvc. I am using LINQ query. I am confused about which query is better sql query or linq query in asp.net mvc.

Comment: Is your question, which is better Linq or normal SQL Query? Or you are asking about Convert to int exception. My answer is regarding your question about the above error. For each approach (linq or sql) there are advantages and disadvantages and it depends really on the nature of your app. The above linq is ok like this, just handle the parsing in a correct way and it will work for you

Comment: Thanks alaa_Sayegn

Comment: @BijayDhimal, my pleasure. If my solution works for you, you can mark it as an answer :)

Comment: Hello alaa_sayegh Can we communicate in social media. I need help in asp.net mvc.

Comment: @BijayDhimal, yes of course we can. if my answer here helped you, then you can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have a list of string that are parsable to integer.

```
List<string> intList = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
List<int> convertedList = intList.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToList();
```

That will net you a list of comparable integer, take in consideration that all values need to be "convertable" strings, like "123", etc.

EDIT: if you want to average it all out, your syntax is wrong.
you need to convert first and average after:

```
double avg = intList.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).Average();
```

Comment: but how to convert it into the asp.net mvc

Comment: asp.net mvc is c#  for all intended purposes, and this is how to use LINQ to convert a list of strings to integers.  ~if this is not what you're looking for you need to give further details in your question.

Comment: another option is `intList.Select(int.Parse).ToList();`

Comment: int.Parse will throw exception when the parameter is not parsable... maybe tryParse, but it depends on if he wants the exception to be thrown in this kind of case.

Comment: This example is using Linq to Objects whereas the OP is using Linq to Entities so this will throw the same exception that are currently getting.

Comment: The `Average` syntax used by OP is **not** wrong - it's a shortcut for what you are suggesting. The cause of the problem is totally different.